# How to go about developing and deploying an SCEP/MDM infrastructure for the Enterprise iOS program

Tags: ios4, enterprise

I am trying to use the new OTA enrollment and device management capabilities in iOS 4 to provide wireless app distribution for the enterprise. So far, I have come across a lot of third party MDM providers that seem to charge by the device. I don't believe this is something very hard to do on our own, especially as a prototype.

My search has led me to some open source software for SCEP. Together with the OTA configuration reference from Apple, I want to believe that the next step would be to actually implement an MDM server. Now, the WWDC talk had slides on various MDM queries supported by iOS 4, including installing and removing provisioning profiles, but there's no reference implementation or even exposed API that I could find.

Does anyone have any experience trying to fully develop an enterprise distribution and management system without third party software?

Comment: Have you found a decent open source SCEP solution? FYI, I have contacted Apple through developer support, and they told me that they're wrapping up the documentation on the MDM APIs. Have these third party MDM providers built the SCEP piece into their products?

Comment: No, I have actually postponed this endeavor due to lack of any documentation. Even the threads on official forums are unanswered by Apple staff. If what you say is true, it's going to be great! I have seen a few sites that seem to offer a paid solution but I am not sure if it involves any of their proprietary software or is built on top of the Apple MDM spec. Please keep me posted :)

Comment: Unfortunately there are a lot of "secret" documents that Apple only gives to MDM providers.  Without this information it would be difficult for you to implement your own MDM server. If you download the iPCU, there's an MDM configuration profile, however there are lots of extraneous things one has to do to get this profile installed on a device correctly.

Answer (score 0):

MDM providers that I've seen are acting as SCEP proxies so that you don't have to expose your certificate server to the internet.

The best open source SCEP server I've found so far is Dogtag (http://pki.fedoraproject.org/wiki/PKI_Main_Page)

woops I was meaning to comment.. not answer.

Comment: SCEP is not an explicit prerequisite for MDM.